# InvalidURIError making request to Facebook Graph API with Ruby

Tags: ruby, facebook, http, facebook-graph-api, sinatra

I'm simply trying to get a response from the API that includes certain fields that I'm specifying in my uri string but I keep receiving an InvalidURIError. I've come here as a last resort, having spent hours trying to debug this.
I've already tried using the URI.encode() method on it as well, but only get the same error.

Here's my code:

```
url = params[:url]
uri = URI('https://graph.facebook.com/v2.3/?id=' + url + '&fields=share,og_object{id,url,engagement}&access_token=' + CONFIG['fb_access_token'])
req = Net::HTTP::Post.new(uri.path)
req.set_form_data('fields' => 'og_object[engagement]','access_token' => CONFIG['fb_access_token'])

res = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
res.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE
res.use_ssl = true

response = nil
res.start do |http|
    response = http.request(req)
end

response = http.request(req)

output = ""
output << "#{response.body} <br />"
return output
```

And the error I'm receiving:

```
URI::InvalidURIError - bad URI(is not URI?): https://graph.facebook.com/v2.3/?id=http://www.wikipedia.org&fields=share,og_object{id,url,engagement}&access_token=960606020650536|eJC0PoCARFaqKZWZHdwN5ogkhfs
```

I'm just exhausted at this point so if I left out any important information just let me know and I'll respond with it as soon as I can. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is you're just dumping strings into your URI without escaping them first.

Since you're using Sinatra you can use `Rack::Utils.build_query` to construct your URI's query component with the values correctly escaped:

```
uri = URI('https://graph.facebook.com/v2.3/')
uri.query = Rack::Utils.build_query(
  id: url,
  fields: 'share,og_object{id,url,engagement}',
  access_token: CONFIG['fb_access_token']
)
```

Comment: Thank you! I'm not at work anymore but I'll try it first thing in the morning and give you credit if it works